# Counting items occurence in a list - the python way

Tags: python, list

The code I have:

```
result = 0
for line_A in text_A:
    for line_B in text_B:
        if line_A in line_B:
            result += 1
            break
return result / len(text_A)
```

It's pretty straightforward: if `line_A` from `text_A` exists in `text_B`, count it and check another one. I wonder if I'm missing some utility tool or is this approach 100% correct? tia

Comment: `line_A in line_B` - do you really mean `in` there? If text A has the line `ham` and text B has the line `hamburger`, do you want to count it as a match? (If so, have you removed newlines from the ends of your strings?)

Comment: @user2357112 Yes, it's a part of a prototype and that `in` will be replaced with more robust matching

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can convert both the texts to sets and take the intersection, like this

```
len(set(text_A) & set(text_B)) / len(text_A)
```

But the problem here is, if there is duplicate text then it will be counted only once. So, you might want to use

```
sum(line_A in text_B for line_A in text_A) / len(text_A)
```

But if the `line_A` can be anywhere in `line_B`, then what you have is correct and that can be written succinctly like this

```
sum(any(line_A in line_B for line_B in text_B) for line_A in text_A)/len(text_A)
```

Comment: I don't quite get the 3rd one. Where would it work where the 2nd solution would not?

Comment: @wils484 Second solution will match exact lines, but the third one will match even if `line_A` is a substring of `line_B`.

Comment: Yep, the code I have does what I need it to do. Correct output for `text_A = ['ab','cd']` and `text_B = ['abab','cdab','cd']` should be 2/2 = `1`. I like the succinct version, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If i understood your question correct, this might be helpful:

```
from collections import Counter

>>> text_a = 'some text'
>>> a = Counter(text_a.split())
>>> text_b = 'other text'
>>> b = Counter(text_b.split())
>>> a & b
Counter({'text': 1})
```